# When I submit my app to the Apple app-store do they see my source code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

When I submit my app to the Apple app-store do they see my source code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**No.**

You just submit an executable.

However, I'm pretty sure they check what OS symbols your app links to so they can make sure you're not using undocumented APIs, which could lead to security problems etc.

Answer (score 0):

No. You just send them the finished product.